# Computer Vision Analysis

Tags: java, image, api

Can anyone tell me what's a good Framework or API that allows multiple text detection on an image. Ideally I want the texts locations (coordinates) on the image. I've been looking for a while but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: You could possibly implement one by yourself in case you don't find it. There are libraries such as OpenCV that could give you some clues.

Comment: @IHawk - I was thinking I might have to write an algorithm that does it for me. However, I've never written an algorithm for image analysis and I'm wondering if it's possible to complete this in a short period of time.

Answer (score 0):

That seems a bit tricky, unless you can simplify the problem a little. Now is the text handwritten or printed ? And is it front facing (parallel to image plane). The simplest would be to use a OCR or character recognition application (with perspective distortion, if it is not parallel to image plane) and create a score, which can be tresholded. If there are many characters, the accuracy would increase. But it might be pretty computationally intense, unless you have an approx "scale" of the characters, because you are searching in scale, location, and perspetive distortion, which can be a huge space to search.

Comment: The text is printed. It is front facing.

So far have you used any algorithm that allows that sort of detection? I've been reading a bit on the algorithms out there, most of which do the same thing in different ways.

Let me explain a little more. Right now you're looking at your computer screen. Now you see this word -> "Sumod". What I want the algorithm to do is to give me the coordinates of that word. It takes  as input Sumod and locates it on the image.

Comment: Did you try the brute-force way: Store the characters and the associated printed character (upper case and lower case) and then search concatenated words and take a normalized score, which can be tresholded. Can you give a sample image. If it is really neat clean like the text on this site, it would very straightforward. PS: If the jargon is throwing you off, please let me know and I can explain more in detail.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please.

Comment: Few quick questions, can the input be "sumod" as image instead of text ?